# npm install -g ionic weird behavior

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, node-modules

Ionic is working fine on my 1st machine. However I am unable to install ionic on the second system. Both of the systems using windows 10 64 bit

```
C:\>npm install -g ionic     
npm ERR! code E404    
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-framework@1.6.1
```

and sometime

```
npm ERR! code E404 
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/utils-fs@1.1.0 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-21T17_19_12_398Z-debug.log
```

My Node and  NPM info is
C:>npm -v => 6.4.1 
C:>node -v  => v10.15.1

Comment: try npm i -g @ionic/cli-framework@1.6.1 @ionic/utils-fs@1.1.0

Comment: When i run "npm install -g ionic@4.10.3". npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/utils-fs@1.1.0 generated

Comment: "npm i -g @ionic/cli-framework@1.6.1" npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-framework@1.6.1

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors